# How to make rsync run automatically when a new file or directory is added?

Tags: rsync

I decided to use rsync for backing up my downloaded torrents from my home-server to my laptop. I read the whole manual, but I didn't find a way to sync files automatically when a new file or directory is added to the complete torrents directory.

The Best thing I could find was running rsync daily by a cron-job, But I want it to be more intelligent, like Ubuntu-One and do the job just when a new thing adds.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/

Comment: http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2011-01/07-watcher_a_recursive_incron_alternative

Comment: Check this out, it's a daemon that does what you want: https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the "script-torrent-done" options in transmission's settings.json and pointed that to a script which syncs the home-server Downloaded torrents' file with my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `inotifywait`, from the `inotify-tools` package, which uses the `inotify` mechanism.

reference:
http://blog.lagentz.com/general/automate-your-shell-scripts-using-inotify-and-inotifywait/
http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait